# Combine Two MySQL Search Queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following method to create a search query that scores the search term by occurrence:

```
public function findAll($search, array $data = []) {
    $query = DB::query("
        SELECT 
        SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
        *, 
        SUM(MATCH(text) AGAINST('{$search}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as score 
        FROM " . DB::prefix() . "search_index 
        WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST('{$search}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  
        OR text LIKE '%{$search}%' 
        GROUP BY language_id, type, object_id 
        ORDER BY score DESC 
        LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . ", " . (int)$data['limit'] . "
    ");

    $count = DB::query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS total");

    return [
        'count' => (int)$count->row['total'],
        'query' => $query->rows
    ];
}
```

This works beautifully, but I need to add in a query to the `tag` table so that it will increment the score and add items to the array for content that may not already exist in the main query:

```
$tags = DB::query("
    SELECT * FROM " . DB::prefix() . "tag 
    WHERE tag = '{$search}'
");
```

Any ideas on how to implement this into the main query so that I'm only executing a single query?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve all columns from `tag` table or just one? If you want to get a single column, you can try to join `search_index` with `tag` using the `$search` value as joining condition: `search_index join tag on tag.tag = '$search'`. Then, maybe it's possible to use `GROUP_CONCAT` function to get the value you want as a list. Try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes I need to retrieve all columns from `tag` as I need to match up other columns to ensure I'm not duplicating results.  The main query is doing a fulltext search on the content and title of a given article, product, page etc. But, the user has the option of adding a tag that may or may not be included in the title or content. So they may have an article about Apple, but they add a tag of `imac` even though it's not in the article, it should still be found and point to the given Apple article.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can retrieve everything within a single query. Anyway, it seems to me the results are not completely related. Maybe get them in only one query can be more complex and still have a poor performance. If you're not having issues with the execution time, I recommend you to stick with two separated queries.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to combine these with a UNION query:

```
$query = DB::query("
    (SELECT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    type, object_id, language_id, 
    SUM(MATCH(text) AGAINST('{$search}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as score 
    FROM " . DB::prefix() . "search_index 
    WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST('{$search}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  
    OR text LIKE '%{$search}%' 
    GROUP BY language_id, type, object_id 
    ORDER BY score DESC 
    LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . ", " . (int)$data['limit'] . ")
    UNION DISTINCT
    (SELECT 
        section, element_id, language_id, tag 
    FROM " . DB::prefix() . "tag 
    WHERE tag = '{$search}')
");
```